# Procedure to change Credential Provider GUID for deployment

Tags: c++, guid, credential-providers

I have modified the 'SampleAllControlsCredentialProvider' from Windows Vista samples using Visual Studio 2013. I need to change its GUID before deploying it to the production systems. I have generated the GUID using visual studio create gui tool and changed the GUID in .vcproj, .vcxproj and .sln files. Also, put the same GUID in register.reg file. Now, the registry entries are made with this new GUID but credential provider does not load. If I use the old GUID in register.reg (that came with the sample), only then the credential provider loads on startup.

As I am new to deployment of such projects involving GUIDs, what is the right way to change the GUID properly before deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the GUID in `.vcproj`, `.vcxproj` and `.sln` files is not required.

You must change the GUID in `guid.h`, `Register.reg` and `Unregister.reg` files.