# How to install custom Credential Provider in Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I want to "install" a credential provider.

What I have already done: 
I installed a vm with windows 8.1. Downloaded the Windows 8 Sample. Built the dll with Visual Studio. Copied the dll to the System32 folder in my VM and executed the register.reg file in the VM.

So I´m asking if these steps were right and if the dll file should have a special name?

Comment: Did you encounter any particular issue? If so, explain it, in detail, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You could also look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52189782/3868464)

Answer (score 0):

look at:
https://github.com/DavidWeiss2/windows-Credential-Provider-library

the most relevant link from there is:
[Credential Providers in Windows 10 - Microsoft Windows 10 summary page in the MSDN (still kind of a WIP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt158211(v=vs.85).aspx)